# How to store a DataFrame inside a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with various text and numeric columns which I use like a database.  Since a column can be of dtype object, I can also store more complex objects inside a single cell, like a numpy array.

How could I store another DataFrame inside a cell?

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([1,'a'])
df2=pd.DataFrame([2,'b'])
```

This assigment fails:

```
df1.loc[0,0] = df2

ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame
```

PS. It is not a duplicate question as suggested below since I do not want to concatenate the "sub"-DataFrames

Comment: Does the failing statement work with just `= 1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataFrame of DataFrames with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368598/dataframe-of-dataframes-with-pandas)

Comment: What is the purpose of nesting a dataframe within one? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Consider a dictionary or list of dataframes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use set_value:

```
df1.set_value(0,0,df2)
```

or:

```
df1.iat[0,0]=df2
```

Since .set_value has been deprecated since version 0.21.0.

Comment: ...or df1.at[0,0]=df2 for labels... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Convert your df1 to a dict by using `to_dict`

```
df1.loc[0,0] = [df2.to_dict()]
df1
Out[862]:
                       0
0  [{0: {0: 2, 1: 'b'}}]
1                      a
```

If you need convert it back to dataframe , You can using dataframe constructor

```
pd.DataFrame(df1.loc[0,0][0])


Out[864]: 
   0
0  2
1  b
```